# Compliment probability

Tags: probability

Two events A and B have the following probabilities: P[A] = 0.4, P[B] = 0.5, and P[A ∩ B] = 0.3

```
 Calculate the following:
(a) P[A ∪ B] =0.6
(b) P[A ∩ '] = 0.1
(c) P[A' ∪ '] =0.7
```

I get this which is incorrect:

P[' ∪ '] = P(A')+p(B')-P(A ∩ B) =0.6

What is the correct formula.

Comment: What does the prime mean, and what does the overline mean? I would have thought both of them meant complement. Also, you haven't told us the probability of the intersection.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Edited!

Comment: Anyway, a Venn diagram should make everything clear.

Comment: @Newbie It is equivalent to the formula for $P(A \cup B)$: $P(A' \cup B')=P(A')+P(B')-P(A' \cap B')$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)   $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)=0.4+0.5-0.3=0.6$

b)  $P(A \cup \overline{B})=P(A)-P((A \cap B)=0.4-0.3=0.1$

c) Using one of De Morgan's law

$P(\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})=P(\overline{A\cap B})=1-0.3=0.7$